# List of object in C++

Tags: c++

I trying to save write a list of objects. I don't know how to check if the created object was really saved, for now I try to test it by calculating the list size

```
     void Hash::insertTest(Customer *cl) { 
      int index = hashFunction(cl->code); //OK
      clientes[index].push_back(*cl); 
      int sizetable = sizeof(clientes)/sizeof(clientes[0]); /// I Think this is wrong.
      cout << "size" << sizetable << endl; //prints 0, no insert worked
    }
```

List:

```
list<Customer> *clientes;
```

[Full Code is here with a web compiler](http://cpp.sh/9bkzq)

Comment: Did you skip something crucial? Based on just the code provided, there is no customers list (nothing is ever assigned to `customers`). Beyond that, your calculation of `sizetable` is wrong and cannot work. Please use that information to narrow down your issue to a [mre] using just a few lines of code with no need to mention hashing.

Comment: You're managing raw pointers inside the class to manage your buckets, and even worse, those raw pointers are supplied by the client code outside the class. Also don't put "using namespace std" in a header. "ini" is not a constructor. This won't compile because Hash::Hash(int) is not provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, already you did it :) Please check my comments and [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) source :)

```
void Hash::insertTest(Customer *cl) { 
  int index = hashFunction(cl->code); //OK
  clientes[index].push_back(*cl); 
  int sizetable = sizeof(clientes)/sizeof(clientes[0]); /// I Think this is wrong.
  cout << "size" << sizetable << endl; //prints 0, no insert worked
  cout << "Look -> " << clientes[index].front().name<<endl; //// You already save client in this list.
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought it was a problem with pointers, apparently, I just didn't know how to present it, I will rephrase the question, thank you again